# Segue to another storyboard without using Storyboard Reference?

Tags: swift, xcode

I have a button in my App which gives an alert when clicked, and only if the user clicks "OK" - I want to send them to another storyboard. Is it possible to do this in the ViewController? Without a storyboard reference? How will the code look like?

Answer (score 2):

Based on the updated details from your comments, you will need to instantiate your viewController in your storyboard and perform the navigation manually like so:

```
let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Alert!", message: "Do the thing", preferredStyle: .alert)
let action = UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .default) { (action) in
    let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Bussturen", bundle: nil)
    let viewController = storyboard.instantiateViewController(identifier: "BussturenViewController") as! BussturenViewController
    //Do any more setup you might need to do for your viewController before navigation
    self.navigationController?.pushViewController(viewController, animated: true)
}
alert.addAction(action)
self.present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

Please also note that this assumes that in the Identity Inspector in your storyboard you have your `BussturenViewController` set as "BussturenViewController"

Comment: Thanks for your answer, code gives no error. However, when I try to run it I get this "*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Storyboard (<UIStoryboard: 0x6000010b5080>) doesn't contain a view controller with identifier 'BussturenViewController'" - i'm assuming its regarded to what you said about the identity inspector? I didn't fully understand what you mean. In which storyboard should I change it?

Comment: I was able to get rid of the error, but still, it does not send me to the new storyboard when clicking OK.

Comment: @lamalama69 Are you actually using a navigationController?  I put that in just as an assumption, but if you aren't you will need to present the viewController in a different way.

Answer (score 1):

Place the below code

```
// Your button tap function
@IBAction func buttonClickAction(_ sender: Any) {
   let alert = UIAlertController(title: "", message: "Show me next view controller", preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.alert)
    alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .default, handler: { _ in
        self.displayNextViewController()
    }))
    alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "NO", style: .default, handler: nil))
    self.present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
}

// Function which loads next view controller
func displayNextViewController() {
  let nextViewController = NextViewController() as UIViewController
  self.navigationController?.pushViewController(nextViewController, animated: true)
}
```

You can customize the nextVC instantiation based on your requirement. Hope this helps for you!

Comment: thanks for your reply. i'm getting a few errors with this code. on the addAction for "OK" I get the error "Value of type 'ViewController' has no member 'displayNextViewController'" - also on the func for displayNextViewController, I get this error "Attribute 'private' can only be used in a non-local scope"

Comment: thanks for helping. I get no errors now, but it does not send me to the other storyboard when clicking OK on the alert. do you see what I have done wrong? The storyboard I want to have displayed is called "Bussturen.storyboard" and its viewcontroller is "BussturenViewController.swift". here is my code: https://imgur.com/a/xix1ims

Answer (score 0):

by looking at the help from all the answers, I was able to find a solution:

```
    func displayNextViewController() {

    let storyBoard : UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Bussturen", bundle:nil)
    let nextViewController = storyBoard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "BussturenViewController") as! BussturenViewController
    nextViewController.modalPresentationStyle = .fullScreen
    self.present(nextViewController, animated:false, completion:nil)
}

@IBAction func bussturenTapped(_ sender: UIButton) {


    let alert = UIAlertController(title: "", message: "Show me next view controller", preferredStyle: UIAlertController.Style.alert)
    alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .default, handler: {_ in self.displayNextViewController() }))

    alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "NO", style: .default, handler: nil))
    self.present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)



}
```